# Optimize search for the convex hull

Tags: python, optimization, convex-hull

I have a large matrix, or 2D array, `M` of floats.  Right now, my matrix has 10,000 rows and 31 columns.  Each row in this matrix represents a vector.  I am looking to compute the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of the set of rows.

Since this matrix is quite large, I am looking for a fast approach.  My current approach [uses this package](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html) which can be as slow as O(n²), where n is the number of vectors.  My goal is to scale this algorithm to even larger matrices.

Are there faster approaches than the O(n²) speed?

I prefer to use Python, but I'm not looking for code.  I'm looking for a general algorithm that I can code on my own.

Comment: You could consider putting this question on http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fixed dimension `d`, Chazelle[[1](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~fukuda/soft/polyfaq/node43.html#c-ochaa-93)] gave an optimal algorithm in 1993 that requires `O(n^[d/2])` in the worst case, where `n` is the number of points and `[d/2]` denotes integer division by 2. The `scipy.spatial` package uses `QHull` which can be as slow as `O(n^2)` for 2D and 3D points. The `O(n^2)` bound does not hold for arbitrary dimension.

Most practical algorithms that compute convex hulls in arbitrary dimension implement randomized incremental construction, which is what QHull does as well, I believe. Computing the convex hull in high dimension is generally considered a hard problem. Check out this FAQ[[2](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~fukuda/soft/polyfaq/node18.html)].

Comment: Is Chazelle's algorithm for convex hull implemented? I know about its linear time triangulation, which is still pending to be implemented and (probably) fully understood just by the author itself :D

Comment: @dunadar I honestly don't know, but I wouldn't be surprised if it isn't.

Answer (score -1):

Convex Hull complexity is low-bounded at ω(n · log n) in the general case (arbitrary number of dimensions), since it can be kind of reduced to a sorting algorithm.

However, you are woking in 2D, a special case known as "planar convex hull". Thus, you can use [Chan's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chan%27s_algorithm) that improves the bound to ω(n · log h), where `n` is the total number of points and `h` is the number of points in the convex hull (this kind of solutions are known as "sensitive output algorithms" for obvious reasons).

Finally, just a remark: your algorithm, as well as [many other alternatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms#Algorithms), have average complexity ω(n · log n), although in the worst case grows up to ω`(n^2)`. Thus, it is kind of wrong to state that it has quadratic complexity, since the worst case tends to be very infrequent.

Answer (score -1):

I programmed an algorithm in O(n log h) in C# than I call [Ouellet Convex Hull](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1210225/Fast-and-improved-D-Convex-Hull-algorithm-and-its). All the code is provided in the link and much more.

Today I finalized the "Online" version which enable you to feed it one point at the time and stay in O (log h) per point. It is faster than Chan by at least 2 times in general usage.

The article does not talk about "online" portion (I will start to write something tomorrow). But the code is accessible on [GitHub](https://github.com/EricOuellet2/ConvexHull) in project : OuelletConvexHullAvl2Online.

Usage:

```
OuelletConvexHullAvl2Online.ConvexHullOnline convexHullOnline = new OuelletConvexHullAvl2Online.ConvexHullOnline();
                    foreach (Point pt in points)
                    {
                        convexHullOnline.DynamicallyAddAnotherPointToConvexHullIfAppropriate(pt);
                    }

                    return convexHullOnline.GetResultsAsArrayOfPoint();
```